# Error while copying files: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, copyfile

Tags: 3d, reportviewer

Error while copying files: Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, copyfile

I want to run speckle 3d viewer in sandbox but when running yarn dev command in viewer file I got above error. I have run already yarn in root folder its run successfully but the yarn dev command not working in viewer folder